# Returning from superclass' implementation of method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, inheritance, parent-child

I have a parent class `Parent` and a child class `Child`. `Parent` has a method `doSomething` which is extended by `Child` (it calls `[super doSomething]` before doing its own stuff).

Under certain circumstances the parent checks some details and knows that nothing more should happen so returns. I expected a return statement in the parent implementation to prevent the child's implementation from continuing, but it seems that is not the case. The child implementation continues. Is that diagnosis correct?

If so, how can I achieve what I am looking for?

In my real application, the parent is doing a lot of work to check whether or not it should return, code which I would prefer not to duplicate in each of its multiple children.

Comment: Please can you share some code.

Comment: One of the solution is return BOOL  variable from doSomething or object/nil and in Child class you can call if ([super doSomething]) and base of the return type continue or return.

Comment: Does `doSomething` return a value?

Comment: doSomething does not return a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One additional solution I am considering is to split the 'test' and the 'action' as follows. `Parent`'s `doSomething` will perform the test. If necessary, it will return. Otherwise, it will call `doThisOtherThing`. `doThisOtherThing` in the parent will be empty.

Each `Child` *will* implement `doThisOtherThing`. It will not have a redefinition of `doSomething`.

Comment: I'm not in the habit if accepting my own answers, but of the multiple decent options here this is the one I stuck with. Happy to hear from anyone who thinks its more flawed than other answers!

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to change `doSomething` to have a return value of `BOOL`. If the method completes fully, return `YES`, otherwise return `NO`. Then you can do something like:

Parent:

```
- (BOOL)doSomething {
    // lots of processing
    if (/* can't finish for some reason */) {
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
}
```

Child:

```
- (BOOL)doSomething {
    BOOL res = [super doSomething];
    if (res) {
        // complete child processing
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But what is doSomething returning a res for? Just because it needs the same method sig? Seems like the tail wagging the dog a little.

Comment: Yes, the two signatures need to be the same. Since you need to know whether the parent completed or not, you need a way to tell.

Comment: I can see why this is the way I might end up going, but I have to say I hate it! doSomething should not have a return type IMO. And 6 months from now `if ([super doSomething])` is going to be easily mis-read to mean that the return type indicates the parent implementation was successful, when that's not what it means at all. It's not that the parent *can't* finish necessarily. There's no error state or exceptional outcome here. Just that it *shouldn't* continue. eg - a method that checks some new data and if necessary refreshes the UI (each child having its own version of 'refreshing the UI').

Comment: I completely agree that this isn't ideal. That's why I started my answer with "one way". There are others.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to extract out the logic that checks whether or not doSomething should return early into a separate function that returns a BOOL, and then call that from both the parent and the child.

e.g.

```
- (void)doSomething {
    if (![self canDoSomething]) { return; }

    [super doSomething];

    // Custom subclass logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To the child, it looks like it's calling just another method. When that method returns, it's just going to continue with the rest of its implementation. It doesn't know that you returned because of a situation in which you don't want to run anymore code in overridden implementations.

What you could do, is use a `BOOL` return value from the super class, and check if that returns `YES` or `NO` in the child class and make your decision whether to continue based on that value.

Comment: I see, thanks. The child implementation of course needs the same method signature, so it too will need to return a BOOL also? Which will just be sent out in to the ether I suppose. I think I would prefer to separate the 'test' into a separate BOOL method in the parent and check it in each child.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a typical object init method that I'm sure you're familiar with:

```
- (id)init
{
   self = [super init];
   if(self) {
        // init self
   }
   return self;
}
```

You could do something very similar: check the return value of the call to super implementation, and do (or not do) something based on the return value, like this:

```
- (ResultType)doSomething
{
   ResultType *result = [super doSomething];
   if(result == nil) {
        result = // do something here
   }
   return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I see the parallel. But the child will have to return something of the same type too right? Which is a little weird to me.

Comment: Your super implementation could return `nil` if it wanted to leave the work to the subclass. So the subclass could return the value from super immediately, or, if it's `nil`, create and return its own result.

Comment: But doSomething in both parent and child will need to change its return type from void to id, correct?

Comment: In your case it doesn't have to be of type `id`. You can still check for nil. Let me add another code snippet to my answer to illustrate my point.

Comment: My point is more that a method here has a return type at all, when it is a 'do something' method, not a 'return something' method. I can see why it might be the pragmatic solution though.

Comment: @BenPackard: I think the confusion here is that you're trying to find a solution that involves overriding the super's method. Maybe it's not the best solution for what you want. As someone else suggested, you can do `if([super canDoSomething]) { // do something } else { return; }`, or something along those lines.